# How to use web scraping to get visible text on the webpage?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, urllib

**This is the link of the webpage I want to scrape:**
https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurants-g494941-Indore_Indore_District_Madhya_Pradesh.html

I have also applied additional filters, by clicking on the encircled heading[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKsfj.png)

This is how the webpage looks like after clicking on the heading[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVfpP.png)

I want to get names of all the places displayed on the webpage but I seem to be having trouble with it as the url doesn't get changed on applying the filter.
I am using python urllib for this.
Here is my code:

```
url = "https://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotels-g494941-Indore_Indore_District_Madhya_Pradesh-Hotels.html"
page = urlopen(url)
html_bytes = page.read()
html = html_bytes.decode("utf-8")
print(html)
```

Comment: You can try to get your results by calling the Tripadvisor API http://developer-tripadvisor.com/content-api/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **bs4**. Bs4 is a python module that allows you to get certain things off of webpages. This will get the text from the site:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs(html, features='html5lib')
text = soup.get_text()
print(text)
```

If you would like to get something that is not the text, maybe something with a certain tag you can also use bs4:

```py
soup.findall('p') # Getting all p tags
soup.findall('p', class_='Title') #getting all p tags with a class of Title
```

Find what class and tag all of the place names have, and then use the above to get all the place names.

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/